# Is it safe to run multiple instances of javac on related java files?

Tags: java, javac

Consider a set of  N `.java` files that have inter-dependencies between the classes they define, such that each file uses at least a few of the other files and must have them on the classpath to compile.

If I spin up N instances of `javac` and attempt to compile these classes in parallel, is there a risk of the various instances overwriting each other's output files and crashing because of incorrect expectations about the state of the filesystem?

Comment: While I can't speak to running `javac` to output to the same directory in parallel, there shouldn't be any problem running multiple `javac` instances to different output directories (i.e. using `javac -d OUTPUT_DIR`)

Comment: Not safe. Don’t do that.

Comment: Note that unlike a C compiler that can work independently on various ".c" files the Java compiler needs the class files of related classes. So if you have class A, class B extends A, class C extends B then to compile class C the compiler needs the class files for classes A and B (and creates them itself if it doesn't find them). If other instance of javac would compile classes A and B separately in the worst case the class file for class A is generated three times, in the best case only unnecessarily wasting resources.